# Add value to entire column in attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table, raster-calculator

Is there a way to add a value to the entire column? I don't think i can use raster calculator because it's a text i want to add, the letter "B".

Here is a picture.

[image: Attribute table]

This is what happends when i use field calculator.

[image: Error1]

---

I forgot the """""""". That's why it didn't work.

Answer (score 6):

Just use the field calculator,  goto attribute table and right click on the table header, and choose field calculator

[ONEWAY] = "B"

[image]

- obviously our fields are a little different, just make sure you select the field you want to calcuate to

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work. "The calculated value is invalid for the row ObjectID = 0............."

Comment: try using a single quote 'B' instead of a double quote

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the field name at the top and select "Field Calculator ..." Then in the window type "B" and calculate.

Answer (score 0):

You want to right click the column header and in the pop-up menu that appears, choose the 'Field Calculator' option. Then in the Field Calculator wizard just Type a capitol B in the box at the bottom. Then hit OK and it should add B to every record in that attribute.